# Proving $R(A) = R(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}. $I'm asked to prove that if $x^Ty=0$ for all $x\in N(A)$ and for all $y \in R(A)$ then $R(A) = R(A^T)$.

To be honest, I thought this would be easy at first (just get $y = Av$ for some vector $v$, ie $y\in R(A)$ and prove $y=A^Tw$ for some $w\in A^T$)... Sadly, I was mistaken.

What I've tried:

Given $y \in R(A)$ then I can see two things:

1) $x^Ty=0$ $\forall x\in N(A)$

2)$Av=y$ for some $v\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Putting these two together we have $x^TAv=0$. But after this I see no useful path.

Then I remembered we have just seen $USV$ decomposition (I'm not sure if this is what it's called elsewhere) in class so I thought about doing something with that.
In class we were taught a theorem which states that if we have $A=USV^T$ by defining a matrix $A^{\dagger} = VS^{\dagger}U^T$ then $R(A^T)=R(A^{\dagger})$ but this has led me nowhere.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does $R(A)$ mean here? Row space of $A$ or range (image) of $A$? If it’s the former, then the premise is a tautology and isn’t going to get you anywhere.

Comment: I guess $R$ for "range" and $N$ for "null"?

Comment: It's not explicitly stated but we always mean range of $A$. So I guess that's it.

Comment: @Jack yes, that's right.

Comment: Hint: the row space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of $N(A)$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried seeing how that helps but I do not get it. From that we have that $z^Ty=0$ where $z\in N(A)$, $y\in R(A^T)$.